# Dividing massive numbers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bigint

I have a `UInt128` holding a massive number like 2000009100000000000000 and I want to divide it by `1/10^30`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly by using `NSDecimalNumber`. For example,

```
let num1 = NSDecimalNumber(string: "2000009100000000000000")
let num2 = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: 10, exponent: 30, isNegative: false)
let result = num1.dividing(by: num2)
```